# MacVim: <Delete> key does not work in a terminal window

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-buffer

I happened to find that we may open 'Terminal windows' in Vim and am happy to stop using terminal app. (It's available in v8 and v9)

However, when I have a typing mistake, pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> key does not go backward and rub it out. Instead, it produces a strange letter 'ÿ'.

The only way I can fix such mistakes is pressing <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd> (but this is tedious).

I cannot find documentation addressing this issue.

I tried to remap but both failed:

```
  :tmap <ÿ> <c-h>

  :tmap <del> <c-h>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Thank @Rich for improving my wording. And the nice-looking way denoting a key is worth learning!

Comment: You're welcome. I only edited it because your key presses `<Delete>` were invisible due to the way this site formats things. If you don't want to use the `<kbd>` notation, you need to surround things like that with backticks: `

Comment: @Rich Thank you very much for your hint and suggestion! Now I learned the `<kbd>` markup - it's wonderful. The backticks used to mark a CODE piece up is also universally useful.  (I used to write articles in Facebook. But since 10 years ago FB removed its limited markup ability (undocumented), I have not been aware that markup writing is so much well supported in other worlds!)

Comment: You're welcome! There's [loads more details about the supported markup available here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

I've just got the answer from a colleague. The following mapping works:

```
:tmap <BS> <c-h>
```

Comment: Are you perhaps typing on a laptop, or other small keyboard? Generally these don't actually *have* a `Delete` key: the key you were likely pressing is called `Backspace`, which would explain why mapping `<del>` didn't work but `<bs>` does.

Comment: Both my desktop and laptop were equipped with small keyboard. As far as I know, all Mac's keyboards have only `<del>` key and no `<bs>` key.  (It's why I marked 'MacVim' at the title - it's a Vim port for Mac platform.)

I have been working in Linux for 20 years. We used to buy desktops or laptops made for Windows. We always have the `<bs>` key above the `<enter>` key. There is also `<del>` somewhere else.  Two years ago, I changed to adopt Mac as my working platform for some reason. I had hard time for 1 year to adapt myself to Mac - quite a lot was about the differences in keyboard.

Comment: Looks like on a [US keyboard](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK2A3LL/A/magic-keyboard-us-english), the key is *labelled* "delete", but it still *functions* as a backspace. To get `<del>` functionality you have to hold down `fn` while you press it. Try picking any of the other keyboards in the dropdown on the linked page: different label, same key.